# _ceil() & _round() same as lodash JavaScript utility library in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

everyone , i want to know anyone create function or package like `_ceil` or `_round()` same as lodash  JavaScript utility library ? i need it , thank in advance

reference link : [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#ceil)

Comment: Don't know this JavaScript library but what is wrong using the [`ceil()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/double/ceil.html) and [`round()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/double/round.html) methods on the [`double`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/double-class.html) type in Dart?

Comment: ciel() & round() in dart it doesn't have precision combine with it you can check _ceil() & round() lodash .
Example :  _.ceil(number, [precision=0]) 
link : [_ciel()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#ceil) 
@julemand101

Comment: @julemand101 what i mean is ceil combine with precision :)

Comment: I don't know how lodash works, but what you want doesn't make sense for floating-point numbers.  That is, you can't have a specific precision in base-10 using a system that uses base-2.  As a basic example, the decimal number 0.3 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point. (For more details, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/)) You can look into using [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal), which provides operations for working with arbitrary precision base-10 numbers.

Comment: @jamesdlin it isn't what i want, 
here example:
```_.ceil(6.004, 2);
// => 6.01
 
_.ceil(6040, -2);
// => 6100```

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in comments, what you want doesn't make sense for IEEE-754 floating-point numbers. That is, you can't have a specific precision in base-10 using a system that uses base-2. As a basic example, the decimal number 0.3 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point. (For more details, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/))

[`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) provides operations for working with arbitrary precision **base-10** numbers, so you can use that to pretty easily create your own implementation:

```dart
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

Decimal _multiplier(int precision) => Decimal.fromInt(10).pow(precision.abs());

Decimal ceil(Decimal n, [int precision = 0]) {
  var multiplier = _multiplier(precision);
  return (n * multiplier).ceil() / multiplier;
}

void main() {
  print(ceil(Decimal.parse('4.006'))); // Prints: 5
  print(ceil(Decimal.parse('6.004'), 2)); // Prints: 6.01
  print(ceil(Decimal.parse('6040'), -2)); // Prints: 6100
  print(ceil(Decimal.parse('0.1') + Decimal.parse('0.2'), 1)); // Prints: 0.3
}
```

Implementing equivalent functions for `floor` and `round` should be similar.